# Should I Use UDP or TCP for over 1200 clients

Tags: networking, tcp, server, udp, client

I need to desing a server application that will connected over 1200 clients.

A Packet flow once in every 30 minutes from a client to server. Server should handle all packets. That is important to dont miss any packet.

From server side a packet will flow to a client whenever user wants to.

Using TCP for this application is a resonable solution ? Considering over 1200 listen threads.

Or using UDP with a self developed ACK system.

It seems like UDP will more efficient than TCP.

Comment: If it's important not to miss any packets you should definitely use TCP. 1200 is peanuts. UDP is only more efficient than TCP until you start coping with missing/repeated/corrupt packets, then it becomes exactly the same.